# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&' in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio-code, console

VS Code is using this command to activate my venv:

```
$ & d:/Documents/TRIS/venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1
```

instead of

```
source "D:/Documents/MY_EXP/env/Scripts/activate"
```

Due to the '&' symbol is this command, i catch this error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
```

[image: xx]

So i have to activate it with "source" command by my hands:

```
source "D:/Documents/MY_EXP/env/Scripts/activate"
```

Trying to run my python file I have the same error on console:

[image: xx]

The & symbol is not the part of the paths, this is the part of command. I tried to open other folders too, but the & symbol is everywhere...

UPD
I have realised the bash console works correctly in a random way. Sometimes when i open my projects env activates with source. But when i kill terminal and open the new one - ampersand appears. But bash terminal called "Python" still have ampersand in it when i try to run file with activated env.

Comment: why do you use Windows paths in a bash shell and you use PowerShell scripts in a bash shell

Comment: Are you typing in those ampersands?

Comment: The real question is: where are those ampersands coming from? Are you typing them, or do they just appear (and if so, exactly when), etc?

Comment: @rioV8 @GordonDavisson @Shawn  No, i dont type them. This symbol appears by itself. The first error appears without any command form me - just with opening the project. Also & appears in command after pressing the "Run" button (green triangle). On the last screen i shown that ampersand is not the part of the path, because i can open file in editor. One of the questions, why VS Code tried to use is and also use  `$ & d:/Documents/TRIS/venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1` instead of source.

Comment: @Verworrenne -How do you set the internal terminal used by VS Code in "settings.json"?

Comment: @JillCheng i dont have this file, i just have chosen interpreteur from env by myself.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having this problem.

Answer (score 2):

From a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67783565), I found [this answer](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-maven/issues/633#issuecomment-845711983):

> Root cause is `vscode.env.shell` doesn't honor what you set in `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile`... It looks vscode team has fixed that (but not released into stable version)

Looks like the root cause is a bug with VSCode environment variables and it's already fixed in VSCode Insiders edition.