# VSCode, Maven Extension with Git Bash: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'

Tags: java, bash, git, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to launch a clean command with the extension "maven for java", but with the Git Bash terminal it doesn't work for me since it adds an & at the beginning, does anyone know how to solve it?

[In powershell works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kLJA.png)

[In Git bash doesn't works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xNW0.png)

[Maven extension launcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImuZE.png)

```
MADMAX@torre-madmax MINGW64 /f/GoogleDrive/informatica/Proyectos/PildorasInformaticas Spring/demo
$ & "/opt/apache-maven-3.8.1/bin/mvn" clean -f "f:\GoogleDrive\informatica\Proyectos\PildorasInformaticas Spring\demo\pom.xml"
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
```

Comment: External links and images should be replaced by readable and copyable text in the question itself.

Comment: What do you mean by "it adds an & at the beginning", for me it looks like you input that symbol in front of your command.

Comment: Thx @gerum, I show you de output error:
----
~~~
MADMAX@torre-madmax MINGW64 /f/GoogleDrive/informatica/Proyectos/PildorasInformaticas Spring/demo
$ & "/opt/apache-maven-3.8.1/bin/mvn" clean -f "f:\GoogleDrive\informatica\Proyectos\PildorasInformaticas Spring\demo\pom.xml"
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
~~~

Comment: Do you type the "&" at the beginning? That should not work in bash, and I have no idea what it does in powershell.

Comment: Add Maven to PATH. After opening a new git bash, directly run `mvn clean -f ...`. Does the error still exist?

Comment: Hello @gerum, I don't type this "&", it is the Maven Extension who types it

Comment: Hello @MollyWang, if I type that command works fine, the problem is that if I want run that command by clicking the play button in the maven extension

Comment: In Bash the "&" has a special meaing, so you can not write it in front of an command. So if copy the command to bash you must omit it, or you must configure the maven plugin to generate the command without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is solved in **VS Code Insider**. You may code in [Insider version](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) temporarily, and it would be fixed in next **VS Code** release.

[image]

Reference: [command always has prefix character "&"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-maven/issues/633)

Comment: @lsiDoro. If my answer is useful to you, please accept and upvote it for people with similar issue to reach it.